# Laravel's Singleton issue (works in Tinker, not in the served app)

Tags: php, laravel, singleton, ioc-container

I have an issue with Laravel (version is 10.10). I have created a singleton in AppServiceProvider.php:

```
public function register(): void
{
    $this->app->singleton('customService', \App\Services\CustomService::class);
}
```

I have a function in a controller just like that:

```
public function test()
{
    $state = app('customService')->func('test', 'test');

    $items = app('customService')->getRecents();

    return ['items' => $items];
}
```

The problem is that every time the function is called, it should return me the first initialized instance of the singleton without creating new ones (d'uh), but instead it creates a new instance every time the controller methods is called.

The interesting thing is that when I try to run the same functions of the `customService` using Laravel Tinker, the instance is persisted and no new instances are replacing the current one (how it should be).

Can anyone please explain what am I missing here?

Comment: Singleton created for each request. It will be one instance in func() and getRecents() - but each request (each call of test()) - it will be new. You can use laravel octane, but.. In tinker - container created once after you starts session - its diffitent.

Comment: You are not understanding how singletons or static data is hold in memory on PHP. For example, .NET (ASP) does store data even after request (static variables) are done, but PHP does not, when the request (or execution, for example, a command, a job, a listener, etc) finishes, anything that is static or held in-memory, is lost forever...